# How to integrate "onprogress" function in react-azure-mp?

Tags: reactjs, azure

I have a React app to play some videos coming from the Backend. To play videos, I integrated the npm module react-azure-mp for a wrapper module for the Azure Media Player. According to the Azure media player documentation, there is a function called `onprogress` to call a Xmlhttprequest. I need to call this function in the npm module but failed what I tried so far. **The video is playing with the basic features properly but the onprogress function isn't working.** This is the react-azure-mp and what I have tried

```
import { AzureMP } from 'react-azure-mp';

onProgress = () => {
    console.log("working...");
}

<AzureMP
    options={{ controls: true, autoplay: false }}
    onprogress={this.onProgress} // this is not working
    adaptRatio={[4, 3]}
    src={[{ src: video.resourceUrl }]}
/>
```

Azure media Player docs - XMLHTTPRequests : https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#amp.xmlhttprequestwrapper.onprogress

How can I integrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make do with the `progress` event? You can use the player that is returned from the `onInstanceCreated` callback grab the player it sets up.

```
  onProgress = () => {
    //
  }
  const onInstanceCreated = (player) => {
    if (player) {
       player.on("progress", onProgress);
    }
  };

  return (
      <AzureMP onInstanceCreated={onInstanceCreated} />
   );
```

Saw something similar to this done in one of the [samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-javascript-azure-media-player-title-overlay-plugin/blob/master/amp-titleOverlay.js#L122)

Comment: `ref` has the `player` object, but when `console.log(ref.player)`, it says `undefined`, therefore the above `if` condition is `false`. Why is that?

Comment: ref will be undefined until the component is mounted. It should have the correct values once it’s available.

Comment: I'm sure that the player is mounted because the video is playing. So where is the wrong?

Comment: Here's the sandbox, i was using to test this https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-shannon-bx8ho?file=/src/App.js maybe different versions of the library?

Comment: I updated the answer. Oddly what I had previously was working for me. Regardless the `onInstanceCreated` is a better option, this ensures that you have the player when it is initialized, no need to hope it's there on mount.

Comment: Can you help with that how can I get the video progress in seconds? The `onProgress` function doesn't have a "`seconds`" prop

Comment: you can  use `player.currentTime()` within `onProgress` if you pass it the player `player.on("progress", event => onProgress(event, player)`

Comment: Yes, it's working. Now the only issue is, player.on("progress") method doesn't recall for every second. It only recalls when I clicked on the un-buffered area on the seek bar in the video. What is this issue?

Comment: But in your codesandbox example, I can see the onprogress is working fine. The above issue must be from my locale